# Add Annotations on mkmapview and set mapview to the region where new annotations are added

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have a `MKMapView` having many `MKAnnotations` on it.
On a button click, another set of annotations are to be added.

Now on the button click, I have an array of annotations.I add the array of annotations to `Mkmapview`.

I want the mapview to move to that region where new annotations are added without zoom out or zoom in.

Please help me out with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think setting the center to one of the co-ordinates in the array of annotations will serve your purpose

```
[_mapView setCenterCoordinate:annotationCoOrd zoomLevel:_zoomLvl animated:YES];
```

where ,annotationCoOrd is one of the co-ordinates in your array  and 
_zoomLvl is your current zoom-level.

Would be more helpful if you post your code here.

for zoom-level

```
- (double)getZoomLevel{
MKCoordinateRegion reg=self.region; // the current visible region
MKCoordinateSpan span=reg.span; // the deltas
CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate=reg.center; // the center in degrees
// Get the left and right most lonitudes
CLLocationDegrees leftLongitude=(centerCoordinate.longitude-(span.longitudeDelta/2));
CLLocationDegrees rightLongitude=(centerCoordinate.longitude+(span.longitudeDelta/2));
CGSize mapSizeInPixels = self.bounds.size; // the size of the display window

// Get the left and right side of the screen in fully zoomed-in pixels
double leftPixel=[self longitudeToPixelSpaceX:leftLongitude]; 
double rightPixel=[self longitudeToPixelSpaceX:rightLongitude];
// The span of the screen width in fully zoomed-in pixels
double pixelDelta=abs(rightPixel-leftPixel);

// The ratio of the pixels to what we're actually showing
double zoomScale= mapSizeInPixels.width /pixelDelta;
// Inverse exponent
double zoomExponent=log2(zoomScale);
// Adjust our scale
double zoomLevel=zoomExponent+20; 
return zoomLevel;
```

}

```
- (double)longitudeToPixelSpaceX:(double)longitude
{
return round(MERCATOR_OFFSET + MERCATOR_RADIUS * longitude * M_PI / 180.0);
}

- (double)latitudeToPixelSpaceY:(double)latitude
{
return round(MERCATOR_OFFSET - MERCATOR_RADIUS * logf((1 + sinf(latitude * M_PI / 180.0)) / (1 - sinf(latitude * M_PI / 180.0))) / 2.0);
}
```

to get the zoom level of the map add the above code in your MKMapView implementation(overriding MKMapview implementation) .

Comment: how can I get the current zoomlevel of MKMapview?

Comment: check the edit on my answer. Might be useful for other implementations. But , Gaurav's line of code will do the trick :)

Comment: @ Kamath5687 : [self longitudeToPixelSpaceX:rightLongitude];Could you please elaborate the functions?

Comment: check the latest edit. Apologies.. I did not know i missed those functions.

Comment: @ Kamath5687 :As I am really new to maps , I am not aware on it much could you plz help me by explaining the MERCATOR_OFFSET & MERCATOR_RADIUS :)

Comment: #define MERCATOR_OFFSET 268435456
#define MERCATOR_RADIUS 85445659.44705395 

these two are constants.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection.This might help you to understand these constants better. these are basically used for maps tile offsetting to plot our annotations and overlays.

Answer (score 0):

use belo method for move with out zoom

```
  [mapview setCenterCoordinate:cordinate animated:YES];
```